# Python- an error

Tags: python

```
tA=[]
tC=[]
tG=[]
tT=[]
i=0

#this is the specific part of my script, A, T, G % C are 4 lists that consists from 10 indexes, each of which is a different number

for i in range(11):
    A1=A[i]*3/100
    C1=C[i]*3/100
    G1=G[i]*3/100
    T1=T[i]*3/100

    tA.append(A1)
    tC.append(C1)
    tG.append(G1)
    tT.append(T1)

    i=i+1
```

The error I got is :

```
list index out of range
```

For this line:

```
A1=A[i]*3/100
```

I know why I got it, I just dont have an idea to how to fix this.
help?

Answer (score 3):

Because `range(11)` has 11 elements - 0 to 10 *inclusive*... just use `range(10)` instead which will match the indices of your lists (0 - 9).

Answer (score 0):

Python indices are 0-based.

If A has 10 items, A[10] crashes. use

```
min(len(A), len(B), len(C), len(T))
```

as parameter to your range to make sure you do not exceed their indices.

Answer (score 0):

You say that your lists contains ten entries, but you loop over eleven. The `range(11)` call returns a list containing values from `0` to `10`, in other words eleven values.

Remember that in Python, all indices are based from zero, i.e. the first index is zero, and the last is (length - 1).

Change to `range(10)`.